# How to pass array in where clause in code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two table `keywords_tags` and `keywords_tags_company`

### Table: keywords_tags

```
keyword_tag_id   keyword_tag_name
--------------   ----------------
1                Clothing
2                Footwear
3                Fashion
```

### Table: keywords_tags_company

```
keyword_tag_company_id    keyword_tag_id   company_id
----------------------    --------------   ----------
1                          1               7
2                          2               7
3                          3               7
```

I want to select all `keyword_tag_name`  which `company_id` is `7`.

this is my query

```
public function getAllTag($id) {
$this->db->where('company_id', $id);
$this->db->select('keyword_tag_id');
$tagId = $this->db->get('keywords_tags_company')->result();

$this->db->or_where('keyword_tag_id', $tagId);
$this->db->select('keyword_tag_name');
$tagName = $this->db->get('keywords_tags')->result_array();
return $tagName;
}
```

if i run above query output is:

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>     SELECT `keyword_tag_name` FROM (`keywords_tags`) WHERE `keyword_tag_id`= Array

What I am wrong in this query.

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing array in `or_where('keyword_tag_id', $tagId)` because  parent query returns multiple rows i suggest you to use a single query with join

```
public function getAllTag($id) {
return $this->db->select('t.keyword_tag_name')
       ->from('keywords_tags t')
       ->join('keywords_tags_company c','t.keyword_tag_id = c.keyword_tag_id')
       ->where('c.company_id', $id)
       ->get()
       ->result_array();
}
```